# Small-Angle X-Ray Scattering of Bulk Polymers

Tags: scattering, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography, polymers

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to get useful information from SAXS of polymers when the system is not dilute?

This is the type of data we're working with:

[image: 1D SAXS Pattern of Polymer Film]

My understanding is that since there's no plateau at the beginning we can't use the correlation function to get parameters like Lc.

I'd really appreciate if anyone has any thoughts on how to alternatively calculate this! Thanks so much in advanced!